# DotNetty - When I use a Decoder in the pipeline before the Handle I get the message processed twice

Tags: c#, tcp

I am fairly new to DotNetty and I have found the following problem.

I have been through the examples and documentation from Netty.

From what I have seen the suggested design when dealing with POCO's (POJO;s) is to create a Decorder class that implements the decode method and converts the IByteBuffer to the appropriate POCO.
The ServerHandler (InboundHandler) then works with the POCO as its message.
This seems really neat and I like neat. All I have to do is create the decoder add it to the pipeline and magic happens.

Well almost.
The problem I face now is that the minute I do this I get the same POCO being handled twice by the ServerHandler (InboundHandler).
For this sample I have simplified the code so that the Decoder just turns the IbyteBuffer into a string and the ServerHandler just outputs to Console.

See Code below:-

```
public class ToTextDecoder : ByteToMessageDecoder
{
    protected override void Decode(IChannelHandlerContext context, IByteBuffer input, List<object> output)
    {
        var clientMessage = input.ToString(Encoding.UTF8);
        output.Add(clientMessage);
    }
}

public class RawConsoleWritingFromTextServerHandler : SimpleChannelInboundHandler<string> {
    protected override void ChannelRead0(IChannelHandlerContext context, string message) {
        Console.WriteLine("********************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Server received message from client : " + message);
        Console.WriteLine("********************************************");
    }

    public override void ExceptionCaught(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, Exception e) {
        //Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.ToString());
        ctx.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

and the bootstrapper

```
            var bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            bootstrap
                .Group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .Channel<TcpServerSocketChannel>()
                .Option(ChannelOption.SoBacklog, 100)
                .Handler(new LoggingHandler("LSTN"))
                .ChildHandler(new ActionChannelInitializer<ISocketChannel>(channel =>
                {
                    var pipeline = channel.Pipeline;
                    if (tlsCertificate != null)
                    {
                        pipeline.AddLast(TlsHandler.Server(tlsCertificate));
                    }
                    pipeline.AddLast(new LoggingHandler("CONN"));
                    pipeline.AddLast(new ToTextDecoder());
                    pipeline.AddLast(new RawConsoleWritingFromTextServerHandler());
                }));

            IChannel bootstrapChannel = await bootstrap.BindAsync(ServerSettings.Port);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------Server Ready-------------------------------");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is
[image: The Output]

Answer (score 1):

The docoder needs to clear the input buffer. using buffer.clear or some other read that moves the buffer along as having been read.